# Nested Query In MongoDb Where Clause

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i'm quite new and i can't find any query that matches my output.

for ex, i have data look like:

```
{_id:1, 
  name:a,  
  "date" : {
    "request" : 2020-02-02,
    "validate" : 2021-02-02
}
```

i'm having a problem using a query to find a data with a request date exists and validate date null.

i tried following query, but it returns all null

```
db.testing.find({"date.validate" : {$exists:false} })
```

is there any condition that i can use to manipulate data like

`SELECT * FROM testing WHERE request is not null and validate is null`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For request date exists & validate date null:

```
db.testing.find({"date.validate" : null, "date.request" : {
        $exists : true 
    }   })
```

Comment: Hi abdul, your solution works. i wonder how if i wanted to add name : {$ne : "A"} ? . i encountered error if i add it. thanks

Comment: @YohanesLim 
`db.testing.find({"date.validate" : null, "date.request" : {
        $exists : true 
    },"name":{$ne:"a"}})` should work.

Comment: is there any order in using exists and ne and other query operator?

Comment: @YohanesLim For these simple queries, I haven't followed any order ever and my queries have returned desired results. Though I'm not aware if there's some order or priority for some other complex forms of queries.